# 'A pair of shoes is/are odd.' Is there a name for this double meaning regarding singularity/plurality?

Tags: grammatical-number, ambiguity

If I say :

> I have a pair of shoes that is odd,

the meaning would be that there was something odd about the pair. Perhaps the shoes are bright green with pink spots.

But if I say :

> I have a pair of shoes that are odd,

the meaning would be that these are odd shoes and are not a pair at all.

Just saying :

> I have an odd pair of shoes ,

is ambiguous.

I need the one of the first two statements to be clear as to the meaning.

Is there a name for this division of meaning by choosing singular and plural ?

Are there any other examples of this peculiarity in the English language ?

---

In the first statement, the concept seems to me to associate 'pair' with 'is', but in the second the concept of association is between 'shoes' and 'are'.

Comment: Why do you think the distinction between 'is' and 'are' is unclear? Both of your first sentences can only be interpreted in the one (right) way, right?

Comment: 'Pair', like 'couple', can take singular or plural verb agreement; advocates of notional agreement will opt for the more obvious choice ('the pair were inseparable in the first years of their marriage' // 'the pair was beaten by Jill's full house'.  //// 'Pair' has interrelated subsenses ('displays _polysemy_'), some of which virtually force either singular or plural agreement, others of which can be used with either singular or plural agreement merely according to style choice.

Comment: I wonder if your second sentence, "I have a pair of shoes that are odd," is more about the ambiguity of *odd* rather than *is* versus *are*.

Comment: I feel like every part of this is a false premise, and it hides a word-request question without a sample sentence in a question disguised as a meaning-of-words question. No, I don't think "is" vs "are" points to either of the meanings clearly (and if it did, I think it would be the reverse). No, I don't think one shoe or three can be referred to as a "pair." Maybe you'd like to focus on the question "is there a name for multiple meanings that hinge on the singular/plural number?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To some extent, OP's example "puns" on the overlapping senses of ***a pair** = **one set** OR **two items*** and ***odd** = **not even** (of integers, not a multiple of 2) OR **unusual***...

> **pun**  [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pun)
> *a humorous use of a word or phrase that has several meanings or that sounds like another word*

...but I don't think it's *quite* a "pun". It's just...

> [**wordplay**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wordplay)
> *the activity of joking about the meanings of words, especially in an intelligent way*

---

As a general principle, there shouldn't be any difference between OP's "attributive adjective" usage *(**an odd pair**)* and the "predicative adjective" version *(**a pair that are odd**)*.

But because the attributive usage is more common in this *exact* context (for the "non-contrived" sense of *an **unusual** pair of shows*), I think the "wordplay" sense comes across better with the predicative format (we're naturally inclined to seek an unusual meaning when presented with even *slightly* unusual phrasing).

[Here's a link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pair%20of%20shoes%20is%2Cpair%20of%20shoes%20are&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) to an NGram usage chart showing that *pair of shoes **is*** is 4-5 times more common than *pair of shoes **are***, but I really don't think that "stylistic choice" makes any difference to OP's example of wordplay.